# Load data into Janusgraph

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I've built a java class to load data from csv to janusgraph.

Is there a way to load my java class from the gremlin console similar to the invocation of [Example in JanusGraph doc](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/getting-started.html#_loading_the_graph_of_the_gods_into_janusgraph)(GraphOfGodsFactory).

Should I build the source project along with my java class? I believe there should be some better way for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a Java class, you just need to build it to a jar and add it to the Gremlin Console classpath. Simply copy it into the `GREMLIN_CONSOLE_HOME/lib` directory and then issue a command like:

```
gremlin> import com.my.company.MyClass
```

Once you do that `MyClass` will be available for usage as `GraphOfTheGodsFactory` is.